# Regex in c++ for accepting " \"

Tags: c++, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to use C++ library to use regex expression .

```
bool x =   std::regex_match(cInputLayoutRec->InputString, std::regex("^[A-Z0-9-\'// ]*$"));
```

in this case the result should be true (x) if the input supplied is any of these letters
A to Z , 0-9 , \ , ' AND /

Its working for all the conditions except \ ie if the input string contains \ this results into false. 
I tried with putting /\ to cater for this special character '\' even then its not working.
Can anyone suggest some inputs if i am missing something ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct but since you're using C++11 it should be noted that you can also use [raw string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals) like so:

```
std::regex(R"(^[A-Z0-9-\\'// ]*$)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\` in a string, hence it will treated as a string escape sequence (in your case escaping `'` .

You need to use `\\` to have a `\` in a string.

As the backslash is also an escape character for regexes, you have to escape this again, so use `\\\\` to represent the `\` character in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character is used for *escaping* pretty much everywhere. This "everywhere" includes C++ string literals syntax *and* regex syntax.

Your regex definition in C++ should be:

```
std::regex("^[A-Z0-9-\\\\'// ]*$")
```

This is what happens:

- C++ parser interprets the *string literal* `"^[A-Z0-9-\\\\'// ]*$"` as the string with the following contents: `^[A-Z0-9-\\'// ]*$`. This string is passed to the regex parser. Note that two sequences `\\` have been "replaced" with `\`.
- Regex parser interprets the `\\` sequence as literal `\` character in your character class.